# how can I add one minutes in current NSDate of iphone and save in NSDate?

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I can get current date of iphone via this code as

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

Now I just want to increase one mint then save NSString format,
how can I?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Increment an NSDate object in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091113/how-do-i-increment-an-nsdate-object-in-objective-c)

Comment: Please chech this answer 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019709/add-90-min-to-nsdate/29542106#29542106

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use dateByAddingTimeInterval.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *datePlusOneMinute = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60]; 
//60 seconds
```

Comment: You sir are a legend!

Comment: You can also subtract time by specifying a negative value.

Answer (score 3):

Or even shorter:

Objective-C

```
//60 seconds
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
```

Swift

```
//60 seconds
NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
```