# Add 90 min to NSDate

Tags: ios, time

what is wrong with this code?

```
NSDate *matchDateCD = [[object valueForKey:@"matchDate"] description]; // from coredata NSDate
NSDate *add90Min = [matchDateCD dateByAddingTimeInterval:5400];



if ( matchDateCD >=[NSDate date] || add90Min <= matchDateCD )
{

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"r.gif"];//Show image in the table

}
```

I need to show this image in the table if the match is running or for 90 min

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I don't know what `object` is that you call `valueForKey:` on is but presuming it returns an `NSDate` object, your additional call to `description` will assign an `NSString` (the return value of description) to `matchDateCD`.  That is not what you want to do.

This is what you want to do:

```
NSDate *matchDateCD = [object valueForKey:@"matchDate"];
NSDate *add90Min = [matchDateCD dateByAddingTimeInterval:(90*60)]; // compiler will precompute this to be 5400, but indicating the breakdown is clearer

if ( [matchDateCD earlierDate:[NSDate date]] != matchDateCD ||
     [add90Min laterDate:matchDateCD] == add90Min )
{
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"r.gif"];//Show image in the table
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the dateByAddingTimeInterval method of NSDate to add the number of seconds to the time.

```
NSDate* newDate = [oldDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:90];
```

You can then use either NSDateFormatter or NSDateComponents to get the new time back out again.

Answer (score 5):

You also set Hour,Years,Months and seconds etc

```
     NSDateComponents *components= [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setMinute:30];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *myNewDate=[calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Swift 4**

To add 90 mins to [Date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) use [addingTimeInterval(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1948745-addingtimeinterval)

```
let now = Date()
let minutes: Double = 90
let add90MinsDate = now.addingTimeInterval(minutes * 60)
```

For question, swift code below

```
if let matchDateCD: Date = objest.value(forKey: "matchDate") as? Date {
   let add90Min = matchDateCD.addingTimeInterval(90 * 60)
   if matchDateCD >= Date() || add90Min > matchDateCD {
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "r.gif")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates are objects, so it's no good to compare the pointers.  Either convert them to common time intervals (floats):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *tenMinsLater = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:600];

NSTimeInterval nowInterval = [now timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval *tenMinsLaterInterval = [tenMinsLater timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

if (nowInterval > tenMinsLaterInterval) NSLog(@"never get here");
```

Or, use the comparators:

```
// also false under newtonian conditions
if (now > [now laterDate:tenMinsLater]) NSLog(@"einstein was right!");
```

or use earlierDate: or compare: